# Trouble understanding uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I recognize intuitively what it means for a function to be continuous (i.e. no jumps or breaks in the function), but the concept of being **uniformly** continuous seems to be over my head.

I'm looking at the following function:

> $f(x)=\frac{2^x}{x}$, $D=(0,5]$

How can I determine if this function is uniformly continuous or not?

Comment: @Thomas I had a typo, I'm sorry.  Thanks for your quick response

Comment: I'd say looking up the difference between continuity and uniform continuity in Google, and then maybe seeing if you can prove the ε-δ definition of uniform continuity holds true for this function on that domain.

Comment: @gorzardfu I've been reading the definitions over and over and just don't understand.  I've even looked at plenty of examples and I just don't get it.

Comment: Watch this video: [Continuous and Uniformly Continuous Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXkQqCBLRp8)

Comment: @gorzardfu since the limit does not exist as $x$ approaches $0$, which means there is no extension for the function on the interval $(0,5]$, so does this mean it is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: Look at the definition of continuity and uniform continuity. There's a different not in the $ \delta-\epsilon$, but the actual definition.

Comment: The distinction between continuity and uniform continuity can be thought of as one of local versus global. "Plain" continuity says that if you choose any point $a$ in the domain, and any tolerance $\epsilon > 0$, then you can choose a $\delta > 0$ dependent on both $a$ and $\epsilon$ such that if you choose $x$ within distance $\delta$ of $a$, then $f(a)$ and $f(x)$ will be within distance $\epsilon$ of each other. Uniform continuity is stronger, because it says we can choose $\delta$ dependent only on $\epsilon$, that is so this $\delta$ works for all $a$ in the domain.

Comment: @the_new_guy you're right about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast, intuitive, graphical approach to detect uniform continuity is to use the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814402/show-for-fa-to-y-uniformly-continuous-exists-a-unique-extension-to-overlin) that a uniformly continuous real-valued function on a subset $A$ of the reals can be uniquely extended to a continuous function on the closure of $A$. In your case, the function blows up as $x$ tends to 0, so there is no way to continuously extend the function to $[0,5]$. Hence the function is not uniformly continuous.

All of this can be formalized using the definition of uniformly continuity.

Comment: Note: the point is that to squeeze the graph of $f$ in an epsilon tube around $f(x)$ you must choose delta closer and closer to zero as you move $x$ closer and closer to zero. The function will however be uniformly continuous on $(a,5]$ for $0<a<5$.