# Is it always possible extend a uniformly continuous function?

Tags: uniform-continuity

Suppose we have some bounded Borel set $B\subset {\mathbb R}^n$. Let a function $f:B\to \mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous on B in the sense that
$$w(r):=\sup_{x,y\in B\ :\ |x-y|\le r}|f(x)-f(y)|<\infty$$
for all $r>0$, and $w(r)\to 0$ as $r\to +0$. Is it always possible to extend the function $f$ to a convex envelope of $B$ or the whole ${\mathbb R}^n$ so that the uniform continuity would persist?

Can the extension be done preserving the modulus of continuity $w(r)$ when $w(r)$ is concave?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814402/show-for-fa-to-y-uniformly-continuous-exists-a-unique-extension-to-overlin

Comment: @anomaly Thank you for pointing it out, but it is somewhat different question. In my question we may assume that the set $B$ is closed.

Comment: It is, and I didn't mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: That's not uniformly continuous, or even continuous, unless you assume $w(r) \to 0$ as $r \to 0+$.  Are you assuming that?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. Missed this in the question. Corrected the question.

Comment: Do you want the same function $w(r)$ to work on the extension?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, it would be much better for me if the same $w(r)$ be satisfied for the extension.

Comment: Without that, you could just use the Tietze extension theorem to extend to some closed ball, with say $f(z) = 0$ on the surface of the ball, and make it $0$ outside the ball.  Any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the last question is positive. See Theorem 2 in
McShane, E. J. (1 December 1934). "Extension of range of functions". Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society. 40 (12): 837–843. [doi:10.1090/S0002-9904-1934-05978-0](https://doi.org/10.1090%2FS0002-9904-1934-05978-0)

The extension can be built as
$$f(x)=\sup_{y\in B}\ \{f(y)-w(|x-y|)\}.$$

Note that the value of $f(x)$ is preserved for $x\in B$, since $f(y)-w(|x-y|)\le f(x)$ by the definition of $w(r)$. It also easy to prove that the new $f(x)$ satisfies the modulus of continuity $w(r)$, since, for each $y$, $f(y)-w(|x-y|)$ satisfies it.

Actually for the proof we need that  only
$w(a+b)\le w(a)+w(b)$ for all positive $a,b,c$, but not the general concavity.

Answer (score 3):

You can't always have  the same $w(r)$ for the extension.  Take $n=1$, $B = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$, $f = 0$ on $[0,1]$ and $1$ on $[2,3]$.  Then $w(r) = 0$ for $r < 1$.  But of course this can't be true for any extension to $[0,3]$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. But can the extension preserve the modulus of continuity $w(r)$ when $w(r)$ is concave?

Comment: We have $w(a+b)\le w(a)+w(b)$ for a function $f$ with a convex domain.