# A uniformly continuous function can be extended on the boundary

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

> Suppose $X$ a metric space, $Y$ a complete metric space and $f: S \rightarrow Y$ a uniformly continuous function from $S \subseteq X$ to
>   $Y$. Prove that $f$ can be extended to a uniformly continuous function
>   on $\overline{S}$.

I've no problem in showing that $f$ can be uniquely extended to a $\overline{f}$ continuous on $\overline{S}$, but i can't prove that $\overline{f}$ is uniformly continuous.

I know that this question is alredy be answered many times but in every argument there is some step that I don't understand.

EDIT

In [Show for :→ uniformly continuous exists a unique extension to , which is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814402/show-for-fa-to-y-uniformly-continuous-exists-a-unique-extension-to-overlin) there is the following answer of copper.hat:

> (Your proof above should explicitly show that $g$ is independent of
>   the sequence used to define it. This is the key point of the proof.)
>
> Let $\epsilon>0$, then you have some $\delta>0$ such that if $d(x,y) < \delta$, then $d(f(x),f(y)) < {1 \over 2}\epsilon$.
>
> Pick $x,y \in \overline{A}$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta$, and let
>   $x_n,y_n$ be sequences in $A$ such that $x_n \to x,y_n \to y$. By
>   construction above, $g(x) = \lim_n f(x_n)$ and similarly for $g(y)$.
>
> For sufficiently large $n$, we have $d(x_n,y_n) < \delta$, and so
>   $d(f(x_n),f(y_n)) < {1 \over 2}\epsilon$.
>
> Taking limits we have $d(g(x),g(y)) \le {1 \over 2}\epsilon < \epsilon$.

I can't get the last step, how can we be sure that the logic implication $d(x_n,y_n) < \delta \implies d(f(x_n),f(y_n)) < {1 \over 2}\epsilon$ is still true under the limit process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show for $f:A \to Y$ uniformly continuous exists a unique extension to $\overline{A}$, which is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814402/show-for-fa-to-y-uniformly-continuous-exists-a-unique-extension-to-overlin)

Comment: Not completely, in the last edit i explained why. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $ x,y \in cl(S) $

$ d(x,y) < \delta/3 $

therefore you can find two sequence $x_n ,y_n$ such that they converge to x ,y respectively .

therefore for a good n  $d(x_n,y_n ) \le d(x_n,x) + d(x,y_n) < \delta/3 + d(x,y) + d(y,y_n) < \delta /3  + \delta /3+ \delta /3=\delta$

and therefore by the hypothesis of uniform continuity :

$d(f(x_n),f(y_n) ) <1/2 \epsilon $

and by go to the limit :

$d(g(x),g(y) ) \le 1/2 \epsilon <\epsilon$

Comment: Assume that $ x,y \in cl(S) $  $ d(x,y) < \delta/3 $ therefore you can find two sequence $x_n ,y_n$ such that they converge to x ,y respectively . therefore for a good n  $d(x_n,y_n ) \le d(x_n,x) + d(x,y_n) < \delta/3 + d(x,y) + d(y,y_n) < \delta /3  + \delta /3+ \delta /3=\delta$ and therefore by the hypothesis of uniform continuity $d(f(x_n),f(y_n) ) <1/2 \epsilon $ and by go to the limit $d(g(x),g(y) ) \le 1/2 \epsilon <\epsilon$

Comment: @Giovanni Barbarani

Comment: Now i can fully understand thanks.

Comment: @user747167 Why we can find 2 sequence $x_n, y_n$ converging to $x,y$ respectively?