# Function $f : X \to Y$ continuous on a dense subspace $D \subset X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and let $D \subset X$ be dense. Suppose $f : D \to Y$ is continuous. Then $f : X \to Y$ is continuous on all of $X$.

The above stated assertion does clearly not hold in general. However, I am curious if the assertion holds under certain conditions on the spaces $X, Y$ or function $f$, or whether there are similar results.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to extend the function from $D$ to $X$ such that it remains continuous, or do you want a function which is defined on $X$, and continuous only on $D$?

Comment: I am curious when given a function $f : X \to Y$, it is sufficient for the continuity on $X$ to check continuity on $D \subset X$ only. So if you could provide me with a function defined on $X$, which is only continuous on $D$, then this clearly shows that checking continuity on $D$ is not sufficient. Note, however, that I am curious if there are conditions on $X,Y$ when this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a counterexample you can consider $D=(0,1]$, $X=[0,1]$, and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology. Take $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x)=\frac 1x.$$
There is no way to extend continuously this function on the whole interval $[0,1]$.

However there is a requirement on $f$ that makes it possible (if for example $X,Y$ are metric spaces and $Y$ is complete), namely uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for the fact regarding metric spaces?

Comment: You need $Y$ to be complete as well; otherwise you can take $X=\Bbb R$, $D=Y=\Bbb Q$, and $f$ the identity map.

Comment: I didn't checked the answers there but you can have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245237/extension-of-a-uniformly-continuous-function-between-metric-spaces. I forgot you need completeness of $Y$ (I'll edit my answer).

Comment: @jvnv: With the emendation in my previous comment it’s **Theorem** $\mathbf{4.3.17}$ in Engelking’s *General Topology*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thanks for the reference. I have difficulties with the term extendable. In my above question, I have a function $f : X \to Y$ and know that $f|_D : D \to Y$ is uniformly continuous. Can I then deduce that $f$ is uniformly continuous on all of $X$, i.e., is the extension $\tilde{f}$ of $f|_D$ equal to $f$?

Comment: @jvnv: Yes, if you know that $f$ is continuous. If $f\upharpoonright D$ is uniformly continuous, then it has a unique continuous extension to $X$; since the continuous extension *is* unique, it must be $f$ if $f$ is continuous (and obviously won’t be $f$ otherwise).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. True. However, I do not know whether $f$ is continuous, right? That was the main point of my question. I know only that $f|_D : X \to Y$ is (uniformly) continuous, and would like to conclude that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @jvnv: If you don’t know that $f$ is continuous, you can’t say anything: the restriction of $f$ to $X\setminus D$ can be anything at all, no matter how nice $f\upharpoonright D$ is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thanks. I think that answers my question. One final question: I have seen the assertion that given a linear operator on a Banach space $X$ such that  $\|T x \|_X \leq C \|x\|_X$ for all $x \in D$, then $T$ is bounded. This can then not be true, right?

Comment: The proposition is true because the condition $\|Tx\|_X\leq C\|x\|_X$ is precisely a uniform continuity condition (in fact a bit more: Lipschitz continuity)

Comment: @Del. I see how it follows from your answer when it is assumed that $T$ is bounded, but I only assume that $T$ is linear.

Comment: Well, okay. If the question is: "does $T$ admit a continuous linear extension, given the condition on the norm?" then the answer is yes. If the question is: "given $T$ linear such that $T|D$ is bounded, is $T$ bounded?" then the answer in general is no in infinite dimension, because you can make it behave wildly (unboundedly) outside $D$

Comment: @jvnv: You’re right; see the accepted answer to [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28415/unbounded-operator-bounded-in-a-dense-subset).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: thanks for the reference, that's a simple and beautiful proof

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thanks; this is a good counterexample. I think my question is solved now as this shows that it is not even possible for linear, uniformly continuous functions on Banach spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:R\rightarrow R$ defined by $f(x)=x,x\neq 0, f(0)=1$.$f$ is continuous on $R-\{0\}$ but not on $R$ and $R-\{0\}$ is dense in $R$.