# Continuous extension of function in topology

Tags: general-topology

This is a question asked in  exam and I tried to use  a continuous extension  theoram but this theoram doesn't  mentions that continuous extension must exist and necessary conditions.
I think I am not thinking in right direction.

Please help

Question is - Let f :(0, 1) -> **R**  be continuous.  It can be extended to a continuous function f' : [0, 1] ->**R**,  iff, it is.................   ................... 
 Answer -

> Uniformly Continuous

Comment: That's very confusing, what exactly is your question? You wrote it yourself "unformly continuous" (don't know why you hide it). Are you looking for a proof? Or what?

Comment: Probably the same origin as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283768?

Comment: @freakish I am looking for a proof or logical reasoning as why It must be uniformly continuous

Comment: @user686624 For "$\Leftarrow$" see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245237/extension-of-a-uniformly-continuous-function-between-metric-spaces . For "$\Rightarrow$" see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-mapping-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous together with a standard argument that a restriction of uniformly continuous function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: FYI - hiding answers is something that makes sense on the puzzle forum. Here, the only purpose it serves is to mildly aggravate readers, who are forced to highlight the text in order to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuous extension exists iff
lim$_{x->0^+}$f(x) and lim$_{x->1^-}$f(x) are finite.
As f' is a continuous function with compact domain,
it is uniformly continuous.  Thus f is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @ William Elliot Thank you