# Are the zeros same in $L^2$ and $\mathcal{S}'$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\mathcal{S}'$ denotes the tempered distribution space, if $f=g$ in $\mathcal{S}'$, could we conclude $g=f$ in $L^2$?

Comment: This question makes no sense since you did not assume $g\in L^2$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I mean that could we prove $g\in L^2$? The similar problem is that we have $f=g$ in $L^1$, if $f$ is a continuous function, but we can not say $g$ is also continuous.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "prove $g\in L^2$". You are assuming it when writing $\exists f\in L^2$ s.t. $g=f$ in $\mathcal S'$.

Comment: Once clarified, your question would be more or less a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652345

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much!