# how to define $a^x$ for $a>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and how is the continuity of $a^x$ is proved without that definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, definition

I am trying to understand how to define the exponential function $a^x$ for any $a>0$ and any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I know the basic definition of the exponential function for natural numbers, which is $a^n=a⋅a⋅…⋅a $(n times). I also know how to extend this definition to rational numbers by using the fact that $a^{\frac{n}{m}}= \sqrt[m]{a^n }$​, where $m$⋅​ denotes the $m$-th root also I know the definition of the negative power of rational numbers . But I am curious how to define the function for all real numbers, not just rational ones. obviously we will define $f(x+y) =f(x) f(y)$ for all real numbers $x,y$ but here I have no Idea how to extended to all Real numbers.
I have heard that there are some ways to do this using limits, continuity, but I needed this so I can prove that $a^x$ is continuous function so I am confused of how to use calculus to make the definition of $a^x$ by using $e^x$ as continuous function and that would make me ask why is $e^x$ continuous in the first place one can show that $e^x$ is continuous at $ \mathbb{R}$  if it is continuous at zero but how we will establish that if we didn't define it at irrationals?

. Could someone please explain to me the general definition of an exponential function and why it works?

Comment: The definition is $a^{x} = e^{xln(a)}$ which is a composition of continuos functions.

Comment: If $x$ is the limit of a (Cauchy) sequence $(q_i)_{i \ge 1}$ of rational numbers, then $a^x$ could be defined to be the limit of $(a^{q_i})_{i \ge 1}$. Alternatively, $a^x$ could instead be defined to be $e^{x \mathrm{ln} a}$.

Comment: @ZAF how to prove that $e^x$ is continuous if you don't define it at irrationals ?

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5Ex%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5Cin%5Cmathbb%7BR%7D%24&p=1), a couple of listed related questions are [Need help understanding $a^x$ defined as a limit](/q/307838) and [Show that exponentiation is continuous.](/q/2831050).

Comment: Formal continuity is probably overkill. Look up the least upper bound property of the reals and its corresponding approximation property. Every bounded, non-empty subset of the reals has a least upper bound. Every set with a least upper bound contains an element that approximates  the least upper bound with an arbitrarily small error. So if you can construct a sequence of rationals with a real least upper bound, you have as good as established the existence of that real number. So $\alpha^3, \alpha^ {3.1}, \alpha^{3.14}, ..., \alpha^{\pi}$ can be used to give meaning to $\alpha^r$, r \in R .

Comment: @TurlocTheRed I am curious  how did euler or newton defined the exponential function without this property

Comment: @user123 You can define the exponential function by its power series to ensure it is defined for all reals (and all complex numbers too).

Comment: @DavidH can you explain more ?

Comment: @user123 Refer to: https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.2#iii

Comment: As I recall Euler and Newton didn't use a rigorous definition of a limit which arguably didn't come about until Bolzano in 1817, almost a century after the death of Newton. Hence Berkeley's "Ghost of Departed quantities" in his The Analyst.  On the other hand, Archimedes' Method of  Exhaustion is close and proceeds either fellow by several centuries.

Comment: There's a complete account in my Open Math Notes [_Principles of Analysis_](https://www.ams.org//open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110758), culminating in Section 10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, one definition of exponentiation comes through defining $a^r:=\exp(r\ln(a))$, where the exponential and natural log are already defined and shown to be continuous through other means.

However, perhaps a more intuitive approach comes from showing the usual definition for rational exponents has a unique continuous extension to the reals.

To see this, let's suppose $a>1$, as we can deal with $a<1$ in a similar manner (or we can define $a^r=(\frac{1}{a})^{-r}$ when $a\in (0,1)$.)

Note that  $f\colon \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(q)=a^q$ is certainly increasing in $q$, since if $q_1<q_2$, then for some $n\in\mathbb N$, $nq_1<nq_2$ are integers, and then we have $a^{nq_1}< a^{nq_2}$, and taking $n$-th roots gives us $a^{q_1}<a^{q_2}$.

Moreover, we can see $f$ is continuous at $0$.  Since it is increasing, it is enough to show $\sup_{q<0} a^q=\inf_{q>0}a^q = 1$. This holds, since if the second equation fails, then we have some $\eta>1$ with $a^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq\eta$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, whereby $a\geq\eta^n$ for all $n$, contradicting $\lim \eta^n=\infty$ for $\eta>1$, and you get a similar contradiction if the supremum fails to equal $1$.

Next, we argue that $f$ is uniformly continuous on bounded sets.  To see this, note that by continuity at $0$, for each $\epsilon>0$, we have a $\delta>0$ for which $$|q|<\delta\implies |a^q-1|<\epsilon\text{.}$$

Then if $q_1<q_2$ are in $[-M,M]$, and $q_2-q_1<\delta$, we have
$$|a^{q_2}-a^{q_1}|= a^{q_1}|a^{q_2-q_i}-1|\leq a^{q_1}\epsilon\leq a^M\epsilon.$$
Thus given $\epsilon_0>0$, we may let $\epsilon=\frac{\epsilon_0}{a^M}$, and choose the $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on bounded sets, and $\mathbb Q$ is dense, there is a [unique continuous extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/245237/1210477) $\bar{f}$ to $\mathbb R$, and so we may define $a^r=\bar{f}(r)$.

##### Remark

From monotonicity, continuity and density of $\mathbb Q$ we have $a^r=\sup_{q<r} a^q =\inf_{q>r} a^q$, where the supremum and infimum are taken over rationals.  We could also have started from one of these as a definition, and then established continuity through monotonicity, and showing the supremum and infimum coincide.

Answer (score 0):

If we begin by constructing the real numbers using [Dedekind cuts][1] then each real number is a set of rational numbers and we're interested in the supremum of that set. So for example $\pi = \{q \in \mathbb{Q} | q < \pi \}$ is the cut defining $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2} = \{q \in \mathbb{Q} | q < \sqrt{2}\}$ is the cut defining $\sqrt{2}$. Note that every set is just rational numbers. Now we define $x^y$ by $\{q^r | q\in x, r \in y\}$. Note that this is just rational powers of rational numbers and we now need to verify that $x^y$ is a cut. It's not hard to see that $x^y$ is non-empty, downward closed, not all of $\mathbb{Q}$, and does not have a greatest element using the fact that $x$ and $y$ are cuts. Basically all the complications disappear since you're always considering sets of rational numbers. I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

Comment: I don't think this quite works, since $q^r$ is not generally rational.  Maybe you mean to take the union of the sets $q^r$, since $q^r$ is a cut?

Comment: $q^r$ is not increasing in both $q$ and $r$ everywhere. You'll need to consider the cases $0<q<1$ and $q>1$ separately, or do just one and define the other in terms of that.