# Uniformly Continuous & Dense Subsets

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Suppose that $(\mathcal X,d)$ and $(\mathcal Y, \rho)$ are two metric spaces.

Suppose that $(\mathcal Y, \rho)$ is complete and that $\mathcal D$ is a dense subset of $\mathcal X$.

Show that if $f: (\mathcal D,d) \mapsto (\mathcal Y, \rho)$ is uniformly continuous, then there is a unique continuous mapping $g: (\mathcal X,d) \mapsto (\mathcal Y,d)$ such that $g$ restriced to $\mathcal D$ $= f$ (i.e. $g$ is an extension of $f$ to $\mathcal X$).

I'm uncertain of how to show that there is a unique continuous mapping. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Intuitively, what should $g$ be?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76854/extending-a-function-by-continuity-from-a-dense-subset-of-a-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, $\mathcal{D}$ can be seen as $\mathcal{X}$ with some very small "gaps", i.e. missing points. To extend $f$, you try to fill in the gaps. Here's the basic construction:

Let $x \in \mathcal{X}$. Since $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{X}$ is dense there exists $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{D}$ such that $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $x_n$ is convergent, it is Cauchy. Then, by uniform continuity of $f$, $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{Y}$ is Cauchy. (If you were unaware that a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences, try to prove it yourself; it is not difficult). Since $\mathcal{Y}$ is complete, $f(x_n) \to y$ for some $y \in \mathcal{Y}$. Define $g$ by $g(x) = y$.

Its not hard to show $g$ and $f$ agree on $\mathcal{D}$, $g$ is uniformly continuous, and uniqueness (hint: if you have another map, they agree on a dense subset!). I'll leave these as an exercise for you. Showing $g$ is well-defined is actually not immediate. Given another sequence $(x_n')_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{D}$, $x_n' \to x' \in \mathcal{X}$, and $f(x') = y'$ you must show $x'=y'$. To do this my hint is to construct a new sequence out of subsequences of of $x_n$ and $x_n'$ and play with the convergence of that sequence. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your insight!