# Continuous Extension of Densely Defined Continuous (but not Uniformly Continuous) Function.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

1. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76864 for example is the proof that a **uniformly** continuous function on a dense subset of a metric space to a compact space can be uniquely extended to the whole space.
2. And,  $f: \mathbb R \setminus 0 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous on its domain but doesn't have a continuous extension to all $\mathbb R$ (in which $\mathbb R \setminus 0$ is dense). One sees that $f$ is not **uniformly** continuous on its given domain and its range is not compact. So, this result is not unexpected in the context of (1).
3. Then consider $f: \mathbb Q  \to \mathbb R: f(q) = q^2$. Here $f$ is continuous but not uniformly so and the range is not compact. But $f$ does have a unique continuous extension to all $\mathbb R$, being the well known $f(x) = x^2$.

So my question is **whether there is an easily stated condition for the extension of a densely defined continuous function which is not uniformly continuous ?**
I note in case (3) that if one considers any closed interval $N = [-n, n] \subset \mathbb R$ then in the subspace topology,  $f: \mathbb Q \cap N  \to \mathbb R: f(q) = q^2$ we have $f$ is uniformly continuous and the range is a compact subset of $\mathbb R$.  Then $f$ has a continuous extension on every interval $N$ and therefore on $\mathbb R$.
Does this generalize in some way ?

Comment: If you restrict yourself to metric spaces, then this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245237/extension-of-a-uniformly-continuous-function-between-metric-spaces?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa answers your question. However, in general I am not aware of an easy criterion.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven. Thanks - I clarified my question to exclude uniform continuity.

Answer (score 4):

One of the few really general criteria I know (besides the classic and very useful uniform continuous one, where the range need not be compact but complete metric), is for compact Hausdorff co-domain:

> Let $A$ be a dense subset of a space $X$ and $Y$ compact Hausdorff.
>   Also suppose $f:A \to Y$ is a continuous function.
>   Then $f$ can be (automatically uniquely) extended to a function from $X$ to $Y$ iff for every pair $B_1, B_2$ of disjoint closed subsets of $Y$, $f^{-1}[B_1]$ and $f^{-1}[B_2]$ have disjoint closures in $X$.

For a proof, see Engelking *General Topology, 2nd ed.* Thm. 3.2.1, and is due to Taimanov (Russian paper, reference in Engelking), or independently Eilenberg and Steenrod (the book Foundations of Algebraic Topology), both in 1952.

A very specific one, for homeomorphisms on subsets of complete metric spaces, is Lavrentiev's theorem:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be complete metric spaces, and $f:A \to B$ be a homeomorphism between subsets $A \subseteq X, B \subseteq Y$. Then there are $G_\delta$ sets $A^\ast$ and $B^\ast$ of $X$ resp. $Y$ such that $A \subseteq A^\ast$ and $B \subseteq B^\ast$ and a homeomorphism $f^\ast: A^\ast \to B^\ast$ extending $f$.

So at least for your example 3. you have a guaranteed extension from $\mathbb{Q}^+$ and $\mathbb{Q}^-$ (on which your $f$ is a homeomorphism with a subset of $\mathbb{R}$) to some larger $G_\delta$ subset ($\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$ in the reals, as you probably know), which you can glue together at $0$. You could see 3. as a map to the two-point compactification of the reals, $Y=[-\infty, +\infty]$, and show the above closed-set criterion, to extend $f$ and then argue no point can map to $\pm \infty$, e.g.

To see that $f(x)= \frac1x$ cannot be extended from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (which I suppose was your intended example), try the inverse images of $B_1 = \{2z: z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $B_2 = \{2z+1: z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and see that $0$ is in the closure of $f^{-1}[B_1]$ and $f^{-1}[B_2]$, e.g.; of course you can also use sequences to refute it.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't know as much as you probably think I do so it will take me some time to assimilate this.